# Why JMeter Service Testing is not stable?

Tags: jmeter

I create test for web service and sometimes it fails and I run again immediately again and it pass. Test just login and logout. İt does not happend on UI. Because of that I think server doesn't has any problem. I think problem occurs from Jmeter. Do you have any idea to solve that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your JMeter setting for Random Delay Maximum and if it is less than 10 millisecond, you can try to increase it ~100 millisecond

Answer (score 0):

Configure JMeter to save all request and response data, there are following options:

1. Amending [results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) in user.properties file like:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
   ```
2. Using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) with "Record each sample as" like:

   ```
   request\n\r-----------------\n\r|requestData|\n\rresponse\n\r---------------------\n\r|responseData|\n\r
   ```

   you can add any metrics you want there:

   [image]

So once JMeter test fails you will have more information on it with [HTTP Status Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status), message, full server response, etc.

In general given you send the same request (URL, [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers), [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), etc), you should be getting the same response so make sure that JMeter behaves exactly the same way as real browser does and you should get the same consistent results